# "Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected"

Tags: react-native

I have a strange bug with one specific device from work.

I can run my react native app fine on emulators, and on my own device both from terminal and from android studio. But when I try to run the work device form terminal it gives me the following error:

```
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment
```

Mind you, the device is recognized:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
S7M7N15610000083    device
```

Even stranger still, I can successfully run the work device from android studio! But I want to be able to run it from the terminal using: react-native run-android. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this error?

Answer (score 8):

Check permissions for android/gradlew file.

Within React native project root folder in terminal

```
ls -l android/gradlew
```

If file permission is not like below

```
-rwxr-xr-x 'links' 'owner' 'group' 'size' 'time' android/gradlew
```

*links, owner, group, size, and time are replaced according to the system.*

run

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

within ReactNative root terminal.

Source:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8868

Helpful resource related to permissions:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/528411/how-do-you-view-file-permissions

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I have checked what you suggested and it was correct. Just in case I ran chmod 755 android/gradlew, however, this didn't help unfortunately. It is a really confusing error, since android studio is able to run it.

Comment: try "adb kill-server". then "adb start-server"

Comment: Was worth a shot, but that's a no-go.

Comment: @DrorBar did you find a solutionn? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: @MartinPalmieri Nope, I'm assuming this is some weird device-specific bug. However, like I mentioned, I can successfully run on the device using Android Studio.

Comment: Do you know how I can do this in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I also face the same issue.

I solved it by Selecting,
 * Media device (MTP) once after device connected to the system USB connected.
 * react-native run-android